# How can I calculate the precision and recall by the ground truth and prediction values of Caffe model?

Tags: prediction, precision-recall, precision

I have trained and tested my image datasets using Caffe, and the data in val.txt is the ground truth. But, how can I calculate the precision and recall by the ground truth and prediction values?

Could you pls give me some suggestions and recommend some python codes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python, [sklearn.metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#classification-metrics) has a very rich collection of tools for assessing classification accuracy. If you want a simple precision/recall/F1 table, you can just use [sklearn.metrics.classification_report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html#sklearn.metrics.classification_report). Your model doesn't have to be trained in sklearn for you to use the skelarn.metrics.